# MSTest: How to mock a dependet object?

Tags: vb.net, mocking, mstest

I'm new to unit tests, so please forgive me if this is a noob-question:

I'm trying to test a function:

```
<TestMethod>
Public Sub CheckSomethingTest()
        Dim testObject as new MyClass()
        Assert.IsTrue(testObject.CheckSomething(), "Check failed")
End Sub
```

The *MyClass.CheckSomething* function is accessing a **global shared method** which is making a database-query.

```
Public Function CheckSomething() as Boolean
    Dim length as Integer = GlobalModule.GetLegthFromDb()
    Return length > 0
End Function
```

Content of *GlobalModule*:

```
Public Class GlobalModule

    Public Shared Function GetLegthFromDb() As Integer
        'pretend database is not available
        Throw New InstanceNotFoundException("DB Connetion not set")
    End Function
End Class
```

As the database is not available for the test, I get a Nullpointer exception.

Is there any way to mock (or something else) the *GetLegthFromDb* method for the test?

Answer (score 1):

`GlobalModule` needs to be injectable in the class and when you instantiate the class you're trying to test, you can inject a mock of `GlobalModule` in that class. It's also better to have it interfaced.

The code is in C# since it's easier for me, but you probably can translate it easily.

```
public class MyClass()
{
  IGlobalModule _globalModule;
  public MyClass (IGlobalModule globalModule)
  {
     _globalModule = globalModule; // use this in the method
  }
  public bool CheckSomething()
  {
     return _globalModule.GetLegthFromDb() > 0;
  }
}
```

For the test:

```
var mock = new Mock<IGlobalModule>();
mock.SetUp(m=>m.GetLegthFromDb()).Returns(100);//whatever you want to return    
var testObject = new MyClass(mock.Object);

Assert.IsTrue(testObject.CheckSomething(), "Check failed")
```

Comment: Thx for the quick answer.The problem with this is, **GetLengthFromDb** is _Shared_ (_static_ in C# words). Is there an option for mocking shared methods?

Comment: Anyways, your answer was useful for me and my understanding of working with unit tests and designing applications with interfaces. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that's my lack of understanding of vb syntax. I don't think you can mock static using moq, I'd be interested to know. But you can use MS Fake I believe to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research I found a solution that fits my requirements:

I used [Microsoft Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for mocking the Shared Function.

```
<TestMethod>
Public Sub CheckSomethingTest()
    Using s = Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes.ShimsContext.Create()
        MockTest.Fakes.ShimGlobalModule.GetLegthFromDb = Function() As Integer
                                                             Return 111
                                                         End Function

        Dim testObject As New MyClassA
        Assert.IsTrue(testObject.CheckSomething(), "Check failed")
    End Using
End Sub
```

*MockTest* is the Namespace of my project.

Comment: Some extra information: unfortunately MS Fakes is only available in Visual Studio **Ultimate**